# Prioritising Local Changes

Tags: git, git-merge, epub, epub3

I'm scraping pages from a website, munging them, then compiling them into a ebook. I'm using Git for both the code and the HTML content.

I have to make manual edits to some pages, and they're often updated upstream. This leaves me with the problem of how to retain my local edits when the site updates.

For example, I download v1 of page A, I delete an invalid "", and commit my changes; later I download v2 of page A, which has new content, but still features "". I want to merge the new content into my copy of page A, but also apply my local changes.

I suspect I'll need to manually resolve conflicts sometimes, but on the whole this should be automatic.

I've experimented with merge strategies, rebasing, and other approaches to no avail. What am I missing?

### EDIT:

To help clarify my problem:

```
git init
wget -O page.html https://example.com/
git add page.html
git commit -a -m "w0"
git checkout -b ebook
sed -i -e 's/http:/https:/' page.html
git commit -a -m "e1"
git checkout master
git merge ebook
wget -O - https://example.com/ | sed -e 's/may/may not/' > page.html
git commit -a -m w1
git checkout ebook
git merge master
```

At the end the last local edit is preserved but the first lost. I know I'm doing something stupid, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would maintain a branch that tracks the original web pages only, let's call it `web`. Every time you download an update, commit it to the `web` branch. Then you need a `ebook` branch for your changes. After updating the `web` branch, merge it into your `ebook` branch, resolving any conflicts that arise. `ebook` is initially created as a branch off of the initial `web`.

Scenario: Let's assume you started with W0 as the initial state on the web server, then you made local changes in commits E1 and E2. Then the web server was updated to W1, which you merge in to `ebook` to get E3.

That would give you a history that looks like this:

```
W0 -------- W1    (web branch)
  \           \
   E1 - E2 --- E3   (ebook branch)
```

When you download the next update to web, W2, you'll get this commit graph, assuming you also had E4 as additional reformatting changes required because of W1:

```
W0 -------- W1 -------- W2    (web branch)
  \           \           \
   E1 - E2 --- E3 - E4 --- E5   (ebook branch)
```

When you merge W2 into E4 to get E5, Git should apply only the changes between W1 and W2 to E4, which should do what you want.

Note: this process only ever merges from `web` into `ebook`, never from `ebook` into `web`. Merging from `ebook` back into `web` would undo the desired effect, as discussed in the comments below this answer.

Comment: This is pretty much what I tried first. The problem being that after merging L1-3 for O1, when I update to get O3, I cannot merge the same commits in again. So, on the second update my local changes get overridden. Does that make sense?

Comment: It should work when you iterate. I'll add a second loop to my answer.

Comment: Hmmm, that's what I tried. But because the web branch always has the error that needs correcting, and the commit that fixes that has already been applied, Git feels the branches are up-to-date. Maybe I need to put together a minimal test case.

Comment: I can't get my example to format in the comments, so it's here: https://pastebin.com/csY3ZeWZ . I know I'm doing something stupid, but can't see what...

Comment: Hum, I'll try to look at your link from another machine, but it's not loading. It might be blocked by my corporate firewall.

Comment: No luck, I cannot see your example from work.
I suggest you paste your example into the question itself, which you can do by editing the question. Add four spaces in front of each line to flag it as pre-formatted.

Comment: Got it: the problem is the line where you merge ebook into master, `git merge ebook`. Remove that line and it all works. You never want to merge your changes back into master, it's only allowed to track the web site, not your ebook edits. That lives exclusively in the ebook branch. You should only merge from master into ebook.